# Remove marker is disabled after one marker remove from map

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-markers, react-leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I am using the react-leaflet/core library together with the plugin [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) which using the removalMode to delete the marker from map

Below is my code

```
import { useLeafletContext } from "@react-leaflet/core";
const Geoman = (props) => {

    const context = useLeafletContext();
     useEffect(() => {
        const leafletContainer = context.layerContainer || context.map;

        (leafletContainer as any).pm.addControls({
            drawMarker: true,
            dragMode: false,
            removalMode: true,
        });
        (leafletContainer as any).pm.Toolbar.buttons.removalMode._button.title = 'Delete Data'";
        
        (leafletContainer as any).on("pm:remove", (e) => { 
            //  Delete code for marker
        });
        
        return (<></>);
};
```

But it is working for only one time, to do second time need to click again on Remove button

Is there any solution to do it only once sop i can delete multiple markers from map

Comment: I have not much experience with react but maybe it is a state problem? Per default Leaflet-Geoman is not disabling the removal mode after deleting a layer: https://jsfiddle.net/sdwLxp76/

Comment: Did you check if the component is re-rendered after pm:remove? 
as you have then one marker less then before, means data has changed. if it's connected to a state/store, it would cause re-render

Comment: @FalkeDesign Thank you for your feedback, but there is any way to make remove button enable

Comment: @Tomer_Ra Thank you for your feedback, but there is any way to make remove button enable after re-render tha page?

Comment: @Developer007 the leafletContainer is set here as type any, it could be that during useEffect it is still undefined. can you confirm if it is like that?